# Python GET request doesn't return anything

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to use an API that is for flight information. On the documentation, it says that this is a rest API and the method is GET.
the URL on the Document is:

http://zv.nirasoftware.com:882/AvailabilityJS.jsp?AirLine=ZV&cbSource=THR&cbTarget=MHD&cbDay1=1&cbMonth1=5&cbAdultQty=1&cbChildQty=0&cbInfantQty=0&OfficeUser=TEH.WS&OfficePass=123

when I run the API using chrome I get back the JSON file but using python I don't receive anything! What should I do?

```
import requests

rs = requests.get("http://zv.nirasoftware.com:882/AvailabilityJS.jsp?AirLine=ZV&cbSource=THR&cbTarget=MHD&cbDay1=1&cbMonth1=5&cbAdultQty=1&cbChildQty=0&cbInfantQty=0&OfficeUser=THE.WSS&OfficePass=124")

print(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`rs` would be the [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) requests object, you want to call [`json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) if there is a json response in the body.

```
print(rs.json())
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but the main problem is not that if you try to run it on your computer, python won't even end the program, because it's waiting for the APIs response

Answer (score 0):

When you get data using the requests module, you can view the response by printing `rs.text`

**EDIT**: the first answerer used the .json() function which is likely better if you want it as a JSON

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but the main problem is not that if you try to run it on your computer, python won't even end the program, because it's waiting for the APIs response

Comment: I just ran this on my computer and it worked just fine with the code in your question.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using an online IDE and won't get anything back!

Comment: @Sepehr ah that might be why. They can be finicky with requests in my experience. Make a file on your computer and run in from your command line